# Package found in Jupyter Notebook but not command line

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

### Specs

- Ubuntu 18.x
- conda 4.8.3

---

I created a new conda environment in the command line.  After installing some packages, I ran a kernel in jupyterlabs using the packages with no problem.  I later wrote a .py program, but it gave errors saying that I had not installed the packages.  Here is a minimal example to reproduce the error:

```
conda create -n new_env pip ipykernel python=3.7
conda activate new_env
whereis pip
```

> /opt/conda/envs/new_env/pip

```
/opt/conda/envs/new_env/pip install pandas pandas
ipython kernel install --user --name=new_env
```

Inside a jupyterlab notebook (with the new_env environment), `import pandas as pd` works perfectly.  Inside the command line this yields an error:

```
conda activate new_env
python
>>>import pandas
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

### The Culprit?

Inside the jupyter notebook (with the new_env environment), `sys.path` is

```
['/rapids/notebooks/my_code/TF_Models/DAE',
 '/opt/conda/envs/new_env/lib/python37.zip',
 '/opt/conda/envs/new_env/lib/python3.7',
 '/opt/conda/envs/new_env/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '',
 '/opt/conda/envs/new_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/opt/conda/envs/new_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/root/.ipython']
```

inside the command line (with `new_env` conda activated), the `sys.path` is:

```
['', 
'/opt/conda/lib/python38.zip', 
'/opt/conda/lib/python3.8', 
'/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', 
'/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
```

If not the actual issue, this is clearly tied to the issue.  The jupyterlab is pointed to the correct paths but the python in the conda environment is not.  This gives me 2 questions:

**1. How can I get the command line python with the new_env environment pointed to the correct path?**

**2.  How can I get the command line python with the new_env environment to run the installed packages?**

Comment: Is it possible that you ahve an `alias` for python in your command line? Can you check `whereis python` as well as `type python` in your command line? It looks like the python from the base env is chosen

Answer (score -1):

You are using (note only a single `=`):

```
conda create -n new_env pip ipykernel python=3.7
```

try with `==`:

```
conda create -n new_env pip ipykernel python==3.7
```

Comment: In changing the `=` to a `==` we get an exact match for python 3.7.0 instead of the fuzzy match which gave me version 3.7.12.  This did not change the system path pointing to the wrong version of python, unfortunately.